# Proving $H_1=\{\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}, \sigma\}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K$ be a cube in the three dimensional space, with the origin as its barycenter, and let $G$ be the group of congruences that map $K$ to itself. Let $\sigma$ in $G$ be the element defined by $\sigma(x)=-x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

> Proving $H_1=\{\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^3}, \sigma\}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$.

I have already proved that $H_1$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I am having trouble proving the isomorphism. Which equation should I use as function? The sigma?

Comment: $0$ of the additive group $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ corresponds to the identity, and $1$ corresponds to $\sigma$. All you have to know is $\sigma^2=\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $\sigma$ is an involution; that is, that it squares to the identity. There is only one group of order two up to isomorphism by the fundamental theorem of abelian groups.

Explicitly, the isomorphism $\theta: H_1\to \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ you're after is given by $$\begin{align} \operatorname{id}_{\Bbb R^3}&\mapsto [0]_2, \\ \sigma&\mapsto [1]_2.\end{align}$$

Comment: Does this make sense to you, @Kath? :)

Comment: It makes sense, but should I not show first that it is a homomorphism (f(ab)=f(a)f(b)) and then show it is bijective? Should I do this with both components that you gave?

Comment: One can show those properties in any order, @Kath. To show that it's a homomorphism, compute all possible products of two elements. This can be done as the groups involved are sufficiently small. To show that it is bijective, observe that it is one-to-one (*i.e.*, injective) by definition and that the domain and codomain have exactly the same size.

Comment: When I said "compute all possible products", I meant to say, "compute all possible images of products". Is that better now, @Kath? Don't forget to accept the answer once it make sense . . .

Comment: I understand it. Thank you very much @Shaun.

Comment: You're welcome! You can indicate that you understand it by accepting this answer by clicking the $\checkmark$ symbol.